# Cannot move object from parent

Tags: materials, parent, outliner

I'm having a hard time grasping the logic behind how objects works in Blender. I have watched a lot of tutorials on it, but they all show the basics where everything seems to work as expected, but when I follow the tutorials something completely different happens and it seems like I can't undo it. 
Is there anyone here who is kind of enough to tell me what I did wrong, how did I end up with this?

Here's what I did:

I started by adding a simple cylinder (Named Body) and played a bit around with sculpting it. Then went to the Material tab and created the ClothesPurple Material. 
Then I created an Icon Sphere, moved it on top of the Body object and renamed it Head. Tried to to the same with material as before and added a SkinColor material, which didn't work. It kept having the material of the Body object. 
At this point I realized something is wrong, but not sure what. So I tried to move the Head object away, but seems like no matter what I do (e.g. dragging it or go to Object> Parent> Clear> Clear Parent), it doesn't want to leave the parent

[image: Outliner]

What I also noticed is that whenever I click on the Head object, it always goes into Edit mode for both objects. I can't select the Head object on it's own.

Now I know that at this point the objects are very simple and it would be quick to redo it, but if I don't know what I did wrong, I know I will end up with the same problem again.

I would expect to be able to still use the Head object like an individual object by selecting it, but for some reason I cannot understand those two objects are now seen as one single object in Blender

[image: Objects]

Comment: Probably you have added the second part whilst being in edit mode for the first object. So both meshes belong to the same object. Use "tab" to switch between edit and object mode. When in object mode, try again to add some object.

Comment: Ahh, that seems to be the problem. Thank you for your help :)